# How do I create a snippet for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, code-snippets, sublimetext-snippet

So I want to create a snippet for the following:

```
$("input").click(function(event){
    //code goes here
});
```

But when I try to create the snippet in sublime text:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
$("${1:Tag}").click(function(event)
{
    ${2:code goes here}
});
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>sclick</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

Obviously there is some sort of conflict between the '$' of both.
I read through the docs but didn't find anything.
How do I create a snippet for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\` to escape the `$`:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
\$("${1:Tag}").click(function(event)
{
    ${2:code goes here}
});
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>sclick</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

(It’s [the only supported escape sequence](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/snippets.html).)

Comment: Ohh yes totally forgot about these escape characters. Thank you.